# Reversing a string which is written in a right-to-left language

Tags: lua

I'm looking for a way to reverse a string which is written in a right-to-left language such as Hebrew or Arabic.

Generally, as I attempted to use the `string.reverse` function the results were missing characters and odd characters at the beginnings and endings of the incomplete "reversed" words.

For example, this is the code I used as a test(Hebrew characters in the string):

```
local str = "ניסיון"

print(string.reverse(str))
```

These were the results:
`�ויסינ�`

Now I assumed it had to do with the "\0" or "null" character, but I couldn't really find any way to check it. The same issue persisted when I created my own function in Lua to reverse the string.

Is there a way to reverse a string of a Right-To-Left language without that being the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The � is a unicode symbol that it uses to replace an "unknown, unrecognizable, or unrepresentable character." So basically, the `string.reverse()`'s unicode doesn't recognize those characters on the end so it replaces them with the � symbol.

I haven't done much messing around in Lua with non-english characters, but I would suggest having a look at the [Lua Unicode](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode) library page, or look into [this module](https://github.com/starwing/luautf8) which provides support for UTF-8 for Lua and LuaJIT. Finally, this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497800/does-lua-support-unicode) has a good explanation of how Lua's support for Unicode works.
Failing all that, you may just have to make your own reverse function by storing each char to an array and then reversing the order of the array before finally compiling them back into a string.

Hopefully this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

`string.reverse` reverse the *bytes* in a string, not necessarily its *characters* if the string contains text encoded using a multibyte encoding such as UTF-8.