# Random Letters When Decrypted

Tags: lua

Today I decrypted some Lua 5.3 Bytecode, but I'm wondering why there are random letters coming up.

```
AH���U��H�D@�@�A�H��E@F������@�\��H�A   ����U�G�E@  F����I���E@ F���I���E@  F@���I����*p@�� 640@0stringformat%X�o@��@0@��@ �@@@@�@8�@��@��@��@��@<�@��@��@@�@p�@n�@p�@��@n�@��@>�@��@`�@@�@getRainbow0x00HacksHacksBackgroundColor  CEPanel2Hacks 84itle��A�A�@A��disableMenuHacksdragNow���@ƀ���   ���PictureHacksHacksClose_On��E@F��F�   @��PictureHacksHacksClose_Off���@ƀ���   ���Pictu 114eHacks
HacksLock_On��E@F��F�   @��PictureHacksHacksLock_Off���@ƀ���    ���PictureHacksMenu_On��E@F��F� @��PictureHacks Menu_Off��EF@�F��@��@�  @A 130��EF@���@@��@��AI���Hacks CEPanel1Heighti@Enabled$@��EF@�F������EF�I�@�EF@�F������EF@�I�@��HacksPage2CheckedPage3Page1��EF@�F������EF�I�@�EF@�F������EF@�I 192@��HacksPage2CheckedPage1Page3��EF@�I�@�EF�I@A�EF��I@A�EF��I@B�EF��IÅEF@�I�Å�HacksHacksPage1visibleHacksPage2HacksPage3
HacksPageCaptionPage 1 of 3HacksPageDownColor
```

I got the bytecode from my friend. I decrypted it fast but I'd like to know if there's any way to fix those random letters or decrypt them. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The � symbol is used when Unicode runs into "an unknown, unrecognizable or unrepresentable character." So either your decryption isn't working properly and is getting some corrupted characters, your friend's encryption isn't working properly and when he encrypted it, the data was corrupted, or somewhere in-between the bytecode was corrupted or altered in some way that is affecting the decryption.

I haven't done much messing around in Lua with bytecode, but I would suggest having a look at the [Lua Unicode](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode) library page, or look into [this module](https://github.com/starwing/luautf8) which provides support for UTF-8 for Lua and LuaJIT. Finally, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497800/does-lua-support-unicode) has a good explanation of how Lua's support for Unicode works.

Go back to your friend and double-triple check that the bytecode you decrypted is exactly identical to the bytecode after he encrypted it, and make sure that both your method of decryption and his method of encryption are working correctly.